# Native app to WebView and back after login

Tags: android, webview, native

I have the following code right now in my Fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    if (mWebView != null) {
        mWebView.destroy();
        mWebView = null;
    }

    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8000/login");
    mIsWebViewAvailable = true;

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(getActivity()), "AndroidAppCallBack");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new LoginWebViewClient());

    return view;
}

public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface {

    Context mContext;

    public WebViewJavaScriptInterface(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void handleResponse(String response) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MockService.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //mContext.startService(intent);
    }
}

private class LoginWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getPath().contains("myapp")) {
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

From the native app, I click on a button that requires the user to be logged in to access it. So, it will kick off WebView there, which works fine. The user authenticates successfully and ends on success page with a button. When I click on this button, it is supposed to call the next class in flow using the Interface I have created, but it does not.

Here is my JavaScript code to callback the Interface

```
<input type="button" value="Logged in" onClick="processResponse('Success')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function processResponse(response) {
        AndroidAppCallBack.handleResponse(response);
    }
</script>
```

In addition to this, the webpage I invoke - http://10.0.2.2/login does not load any CSS/JS when loaded as WebView. Is there anything I need to turn on to get all resources loaded? The webpage is totally outside of my control.

Comment: Once successfully authenticated call a JavascriptInterface Method which will remove the webview fragment and pass the data onto next class in your flow

Comment: I'm new to Android development, can you point me to an example if you know of one?